# Single post page from static home not working

Tags: posts, single

I'm struggling with displaying a single post page.

I have the following code on the static front page:

```
<?php
                $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'date' );
                $postslist = get_posts( $args );
                foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
                    <div class="single_post">

                        <h3><?php the_date(); ?></h3>

                        <h3>
                            <a href="<?php get_permalink();?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>   
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

That fetches latest posts.

I'm trying to understand how single post page works by copying it from twentytwelve wp theme folder but for some reason it doesn't work.
I would really appreciate any help in pointing directions i should follow to make single.php work.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand what are you trying to accomplish. The code you posted here shows 5 oldest posts. It has nothing to do with showing single post, so...?

Comment: Agreed. This is confusing. You posted code for your static home page but the question seems to be about a `single.php` page for which you've provide little information except that "it doesn't work".

Comment: I want to be able to open this latest posts in separate single.php page that will only show one post.

Comment: Still not clear... are you asking how to make an HTML anchor(link)?

Comment: probably yes...

Answer (score 0):

See the change of `get_permalink` to `the_permalink`

This might work for you.

```
<?php
                $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'date' );
                $postslist = get_posts( $args );
                foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
                    <div class="single_post">

                        <h3><?php the_date(); ?></h3>

                        <h3>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>   
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: For some reason <?php the_permalink();?> and <?php get_permalink();?> are rendering blank for me :(

Comment: Try removing H3 tag arround a tag.

Comment: I've tried pasting it in different locations but it didn't work for me.